# How to add horizontal curly braces with text on top of a matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices, braces, overbrace

I am using `tikz` to make a flow diagram of a matrix appending rows. For the last matrix I want to add curly braces on the right and top of the matrix with texts. Below is my code which can add curly brace and text to the right:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx,supertabular}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (B) {
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 
     \end{bmatrix}$};
    \node[left=3.5cm of B] (A) {
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 
     \end{bmatrix}$};
    \node[right=3.5cm of B] (C){
    $\begin{rcases}\displaystyle
     \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        3 & 1 & \dots & 4 
     \end{bmatrix}
     \end{rcases}
     \text{$N_{\mathrm{conf}}$}$};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B) node[midway, above,font=\small] {
    $+\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
      \end{bmatrix}$};
    \draw[->] (B)--(C) node[midway, above,font=\small] {
    $+\begin{bmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
      \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flow diagram of the matrix.}
\label{bootstrap_flowchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I am expecting to get something like this
[image]
I don't know how to add the curly brace and the text "Columns" on top of the matrix. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--adding the code

```
\draw[decorate, ultra thick] ($(C.north west)+(2ex,0pt)$) -- 
   ($(C.north east)-(9ex,0pt)$) node[above=3pt,midway] {some text};
```

should produce the brace required

--in the preamble add calligraphy

```
  \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning,calligraphy}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx,supertabular}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning,calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=6pt}]
    \node (B) {
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 
     \end{bmatrix}$};
    \node[left=3.5cm of B] (A) {
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 
     \end{bmatrix}$};
    \node[right=3.5cm of B] (C){
    $\begin{rcases}\displaystyle
     \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        3 & 1 & \dots & 4 
     \end{bmatrix}
     \end{rcases}
     \text{$N_{\mathrm{conf}}$}$};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B) node[midway, above,font=\small] {
    $+\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
      \end{bmatrix}$};
    \draw[->] (B)--(C) node[midway, above,font=\small] {
    $+\begin{bmatrix} 
        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
      \end{bmatrix}$};
     \draw[decorate, ultra thick] ($(C.north west)+(2ex,0pt)$) -- ($(C.north east)-(9ex,0pt)$) node[above=3pt,midway] {some text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flow diagram of the matrix.}
\label{bootstrap_flowchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the matrix with the command `\overbrace` as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \xrightarrow{+ \begin{bmatrix}
                        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
                   \end{bmatrix}} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}
    \xrightarrow{+ \begin{bmatrix}
                        1 & 0 & \dots & 3
                   \end{bmatrix}} 
    \overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        3 & 1 & \dots & 4 
     \end{bmatrix}}^{\text{Columns}}     
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that it is not necessary to use Tikz, and you can use the command `\xrightarrow` to generate an arrow and write anything above or below it.